# Issue with passing a JSX object as string

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In the app I am using a countdown timer component that looks like this.

```
<TimerCountdown
          initialSecondsRemaining={100000000}
          onTick={() => console.log('tick')}
          onTimeElapsed={() => console.log('complete')}
          allowFontScaling
          style={{ fontSize: 20 }}
/>
```

It works perfectly fine, but I wish to have the countdown text inside a react-native-element button, which I've done like this.

```
<Button
    textStyle={[styles.textStyle]}
    title={<TimerCountdown
          initialSecondsRemaining={100000000}
          onTick={() => console.log('tick')}
          onTimeElapsed={() => console.log('complete')}
          allowFontScaling
          style={{ fontSize: 20 }}
          />}
    buttonStyle={styles.detailsStyle}
    containerViewStyle={styles.buttonContainerViewStyle}
  />
```

This works fine as well except I get a warning of "invalid prop 'title of type 'object' supplied to 'Button, expected 'string'.

How can I convert the object into string to clear the warning?
I've tried doing this:

```
  <Button
    textStyle={[styles.textStyle]}
    title={`${<TimerCountdown
          initialSecondsRemaining={100000000}
          onTick={() => console.log('tick')}
          onTimeElapsed={() => console.log('complete')}
          allowFontScaling
          style={{ fontSize: 20 }}
    />}`}
    buttonStyle={styles.detailsStyle}
    containerViewStyle={styles.buttonContainerViewStyle}
  />
```

but the button ends up displaying " [object Object] "

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to pass a component as a prop when it's expecting a string. Internally the `<Button />` component probably does something like `{this.props.title}` so passing a component works only by coincidence. You can't convert a React component to a string. You have to live with the warning, or not pass a component to that prop.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the Button component, you could use the TouchableOpacity component to create your own button. You can then use TimerCountdown as a child component rather than as a property.